# Lag function on grouped data

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  {"groupId":"A","Day":"2021-01-27", "ts": "2021-01-27 08:30:57.000", "Username": "user1", "Region": "US"},
  {"groupId":"A","Day":"2021-01-27", "ts": "2021-01-27 08:31:57.014", "Username": "user2", "Region": "US"},
  {"groupId":"A","Day":"2021-01-27", "ts": "2021-01-27 08:32:57.914", "Username": "user1", "Region": "MX"},
  {"groupId":"A","Day":"2021-01-27", "ts": "2021-01-27 08:35:57.914", "Username": "user2", "Region": "CA"},
  {"groupId":"A","Day":"2021-01-27", "ts": "2021-01-27 08:33:57.914", "Username": "user1", "Region": "UK"},
  {"groupId":"A","Day":"2021-01-27", "ts": "2021-01-27 08:34:57.914", "Username": "user1", "Region": "GR"},
  {"groupId":"A","Day":"2021-01-27", "ts": "2021-01-27 08:36:57.914", "Username": "user2", "Region": "IR"}])

w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("groupId","Username").orderBy("Username","ts")
df2 = df.withColumn("prev_region", f.lag(df.Region).over(w))
```

| Day | Region | Username | groupId | ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-27 | US | user1 | A | 2021-01-27 08:30:57.000 |
| 2021-01-27 | MX | user1 | A | 2021-01-27 08:32:57.914 |
| 2021-01-27 | UK | user1 | A | 2021-01-27 08:33:57.914 |
| 2021-01-27 | GR | user1 | A | 2021-01-27 08:34:57.914 |
| 2021-01-27 | US | user2 | A | 2021-01-27 08:31:57.014 |
| 2021-01-27 | CA | user2 | A | 2021-01-27 08:35:57.914 |
| 2021-01-27 | IR | user2 | A | 2021-01-27 08:36:57.914 |

And, I want to know what was previous region of users so I used lag function.

| Day | Region | Username | groupId | ts | prev_region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-27 | US | user1 | A | 2021-01-27 08:30:57.000 | null |
| 2021-01-27 | MX | user1 | A | 2021-01-27 08:32:57.914 | US |
| 2021-01-27 | UK | user1 | A | 2021-01-27 08:33:57.914 | MX |
| 2021-01-27 | GR | user1 | A | 2021-01-27 08:34:57.914 | UK |
| 2021-01-27 | US | user2 | A | 2021-01-27 08:31:57.014 | **GR** |
| 2021-01-27 | CA | user2 | A | 2021-01-27 08:35:57.914 | US |
| 2021-01-27 | IR | user2 | A | 2021-01-27 08:36:57.914 | CA |

As you see the value of "prev region" column in the first record of user2 expected to be "null"; however, it is wrong value. I would be thankful if you can show me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

Simply based on your DataFrame, by specifying the windows function as the following will work.

```py
# Python API
>>> w = Window.partitionBy("Username").orderBy("groupId", "Username", "ts")
>>> df2.show(truncate=100)
+----------+------+--------+-------+-----------------------+-----------+
|       Day|Region|Username|groupId|                     ts|prev_region|
+----------+------+--------+-------+-----------------------+-----------+
|2021-01-27|    US|   user1|      A|2021-01-27 08:30:57.000|       null|
|2021-01-27|    MX|   user1|      A|2021-01-27 08:32:57.914|         US|
|2021-01-27|    UK|   user1|      A|2021-01-27 08:33:57.914|         MX|
|2021-01-27|    GR|   user1|      A|2021-01-27 08:34:57.914|         UK|
|2021-01-27|    US|   user2|      A|2021-01-27 08:31:57.014|       null|
|2021-01-27|    CA|   user2|      A|2021-01-27 08:35:57.914|         US|
|2021-01-27|    IR|   user2|      A|2021-01-27 08:36:57.914|         CA|
+----------+------+--------+-------+-----------------------+-----------+

# SQL API
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
result = spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
        Day, Region, Username, groupId, ts, 
        LAG(Region) OVER (PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY groupId, Username, ts) as rank
    FROM df 
    """)
result.show(truncate=100)
+----------+------+--------+-------+-----------------------+----+
|       Day|Region|Username|groupId|                     ts|rank|
+----------+------+--------+-------+-----------------------+----+
|2021-01-27|    US|   user1|      A|2021-01-27 08:30:57.000|null|
|2021-01-27|    MX|   user1|      A|2021-01-27 08:32:57.914|  US|
|2021-01-27|    UK|   user1|      A|2021-01-27 08:33:57.914|  MX|
|2021-01-27|    GR|   user1|      A|2021-01-27 08:34:57.914|  UK|
|2021-01-27|    US|   user2|      A|2021-01-27 08:31:57.014|null|
|2021-01-27|    CA|   user2|      A|2021-01-27 08:35:57.914|  US|
|2021-01-27|    IR|   user2|      A|2021-01-27 08:36:57.914|  CA|
+----------+------+--------+-------+-----------------------+----+
```

If there are more than one group (multiple `groupId`s), then state the window function as the following:

```py
>>> w = Window.partitionBy("groupId", "Username").orderBy("groupId", "ts", "Username")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add your `Username` column in the `partitionBy`function. Also there is no need to have  two `orderBy` function call. Change your line to:

```
w = Window.partitionBy('Username').orderBy("ts")
```